# Issue with name appServlet-servlet.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi guys I'm working with Spring 3.2.3, hibernate 4.2.2 and org.springframework.security 3.0.5. Before I start working with security in spring, my context file was called servlet-context.xml and everything worked fine. Since I start using org.springframework.security 3.0.5 when I try to run my application I get the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appServlet-servlet.xml]
```

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
     </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<listener>
    <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Notice that I'm specifying my servlet-context.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

If I leave my web.xml just like this and copy/paste my servlet-context.xml content in a new file called appServlet-servlet.xml, everything works fine. This is confusing for me since I told  web.xml that my context file name was servlet-context.xml. Am I forced to call my context file as appServlet-servlet.xml??. Of course, if I delete servlet-context.xml and leave appServlet-servlet.xml making the specficiation in web.xml, works fine.

I just wanna know if is obligatory to call my context file  as appServlet-servlet.xml if I want to use spring security in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not strange. Spring works this way. Since your DispatchServlet name is appServlet, Spring automatically tries to find the servlet context that has the same name, here "appServlet-servlet.xml".

Here is a page that may help : http://syntx.io/difference-between-loading-context-via-dispatcherservlet-and-contextloaderlistener/

Comment: But if this is the way it works, why before I started using spring security I was able to work with my "servlet-context.xml "?.

Comment: Oh I understand better now. Your link was very usefull. Before using spring security, in my web.xml I used The "WebApplicationContext”. Thats why it worked fine. Thanks a lot @Julien :).